Prove that the coherent information of an antidegradable channel is equal to zero
I want to show that antidegradable channels have zero coherent information, based on Exercise 13.5.6 in [1]. So the solution should use the following relationship: For Hilbert spaces $R, B, E$, a pure state $|\phi\rangle_{RBE} \in RBE$ obeys (Exercise 11.6.6 in [1]):
$$
I(R\rangle B)_\phi = \frac{1}{2}(I(R:B)_\phi - I(R:E)_\phi) \tag{1}
$$
where $I(\cdot \rangle \cdot)$ denotes coherent information.

My work so far:
Given an antidegradable channel $\mathcal{N}$ with isometric extension $V: A \rightarrow BE$, we start with an entangled state $|\psi\rangle_{RA} \in RA$ and apply $V$ to system $A$, resulting in $|\phi\rangle_{RBE}$. Then we use antidegradability to show that $I(R\rangle B)_\phi = 0$ in (1).
Say that $U: E\rightarrow B' E'$ is the isometric extension of our antidegradable $\mathcal{N}$. Antidegradability means that for reduced states
$$\rho_E = \text{tr}_{RB}|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|_{RBE}\quad\text{  and  } \quad\rho_B = \text{tr}_{RE}|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|_{RBE},$$
$U$ always obeys $\text{tr}_{E'}(U \rho_E U^\dagger) = \rho_B'$. Applying the isometric extension of the antidegrading map to $|\phi\rangle_{RBE}$ prepares the state
$$
|\chi\rangle_{RBB'E'}:= (I_{RB}\otimes U)|\phi\rangle_{RBE}
$$
With this we can compute
\begin{align}
I(R:B)_\phi - I(R:E)_\phi &\leq  I(R:B)_\phi - I(R:B')_\chi \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \text{data processing inequality} \tag{1}
\\&= H(B)_\phi - H(RB)_\phi + H(RB')_\chi - H(B')_\chi
\\&= - H(RB)_\phi + H(RB')_\chi \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \text{by antidegradability}
\\&= -H(E)_\phi + H(BE')_\chi \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\, \text{entropy equal across bipartitions}
\end{align}
Then I do not know how to proceed. I thought maybe one could argue that applying the map $V^\dagger: E'B' \rightarrow E$ to subsystem $E'B$ should recover a state with entropy $H(E)$, since $\rho_B = \rho_{B'}$ (using antidegradability). But $V^\dagger$ isn't necessarily an isometry and so I can't make sense of applying it to the system $BE'$ in this way.

[1 Wilde, Mark. From Classical to Quantum Shannon Theory (2016). arXiv:1106.1445

Let the channel be $\mathcal{N}_{A\rightarrow B}$ and its complementary channel be $\mathcal{N}^c_{A\rightarrow E}$.
By Property 13.5.1 of [1], we have that
$$Q(\mathcal{N})\geq 0.$$
Consider the map $\mathcal{D}_{E\rightarrow B}$ which satisfies $(\mathcal{D}\circ\mathcal{N}^c)(\rho_A) = \mathcal{N}(\rho_A)$ for any input state $\rho_A$. This exists because the channel $\mathcal{N}$ is anti-degradable. By the data processing inequality, you have
$$I(R:E)_{\mathcal{N}^c(\rho_A)} \geq I(R:B)_{(\mathcal{D}\circ\mathcal{N}^c)(\rho_A)} = I(R:B)_{\mathcal{N}(\rho_A)}.$$
This implies that
$$Q(\mathcal{N}) = I(R:B)_{\mathcal{N}(\rho_A)} - I(R:E)_{\mathcal{N}^c(\rho_A)} \leq 0.$$

I don't see why $I(R:B){(\mathcal{D}\circ\mathcal{N}^c)(\rho_A)} = I(R:B){\mathcal{N}(\rho_A)}$ is true though? This is equivalent to the second-to-last line of my derivation, so I understand that it should be true. I just don't see why the antidegrading map $\mathcal{D}$ should leave $RB'$ (you just called this $RB$) in the same state as $RB$

The reason this equality holds is because, by definition, the degradable channel is one for which there exists a map $\mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathcal{D}\circ\mathcal{N}^c = \mathcal{N}$. Note that this is an equality of channels so you get equality of output states too when the input state is the same.
